# Mongoose and multiple save error handling

Tags: javascript, mongoose, error-handling

I'm using mongoose + express to build a simple MERN app.

I need to create multiple documents and save them, but I need to catch all errors.
I'm using this code and it works, but I'd like to handle all errors at once, not repeat the same code multiple times.

If I use try...catch block and remove the callback error handler, I obtain UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

```js
  model.save((err, doc) => {
      if (err) return console.error(`ERR ${err.message}`);
    });
```

I've tried this:

```
export const init = async () => {
  try {
    const newDoc = new MyModel({ test: 'test'});
    const savedDoc = await newDoc.save();
    console.log('All done :)');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error');
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
}
```

But I can't catch the error: in debug mode, the program never enter the catch block and I obtain, in case of error for example:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    const savedModel = await model.save();
    console.log("Model created successfully");
    res.status(200).send("Model created successfully");
}catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I've done, but I can't catch the error!

export const init = async () => {
  try {
    const newDoc = new MyModel({ test: 'test'});
    const savedDoc = await newDoc.save();
    console.log('All done :)');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error');
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
}


If there is any error (for example, duplicated key), I obtain:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxxxxxx

And in debug mode the program never enter the catch section.

Comment: it should work as you have it, if you want a more specific error hadling you can look [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

```js
model.save()
.then(success => {
  if(!success) {
    // Handle your error
  }
  
  // Success
  return model2.save();
  })
  .then(success2 => {


  })
  // etc..
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle your error
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use InsertMany because I need single document in different time and manage the saved document.
Is there any way to centralize error handling, without repeating .catch(err) each time?

Comment: I edited the post. You can use this if there is few documents to be saved. Could you give me the context where you need to save many documents ?